# definition of line complex in projective space

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

In a paper of "R.H.Dye", which you can find here: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02413785#page-1, I face with a mathematical object "line complex in projective space PG(2n−1,q), I need to understand it, any comment is highly appriciated.